# Show that: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(n-1)s^{n-2} = \frac{2}{(1-s)^3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I show that:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n(n-1)s^{n-2} = \frac{2}{(1-s)^3}$

I'm struggling to figure out how to start on this question. Should I sum the series and then differentiate it and also differentiate the sum term by term and then equate the two together? Would that be the right method of going about it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: 
$$
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} n (n-1) s^{n-2} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d^2}{ds^2} s^n
$$

Comment: Can you explain what you did here?

Comment: The "power rule" for derivatives tells us 
$$ \frac{d^2}{ds^2}s^n = n(n-1)s^{n-2}$$ So, what you see in the summand is just the second derivative of $s^n$ with respect to $s$. From here you can interchange the sum and derivatives (as long as $|s|<1$).

Comment: Ah yes I see now, thank you